# Let $x\in X$ and $S\subset X$ be countable and dense. Is there a sequence in $S$ converging to $x$?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, separable-spaces

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a separable topological space and $S\subset X$ be a countable dense subset.

> $(1)$ For any $x\in X$ can we find a sequence of elements in $S$ that converges to $x$?
>
> $(2)$ For any non-isolated $x\in X$, can we find a sequence of elements in $X\setminus \{x\}$ that converges to $x$?

If $(X,\tau)$ is $T_1$ then $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$.

If $(X,\tau)$ is first countable then $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold.

If $\tau$ is the [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) the $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold.

To prove $(1)$ if suffices to show the following:

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that has the [finite intersection property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property), there exists a sequence $(a_n)_n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that, for every $F\in\mathcal{F}$, sequence $(a_n)_n$ belongs eventually in $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you wish to prove is not true. A counterexample is given by [the Stone-Čech compactification of $\mathbb N$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#The_Stone.E2.80.93.C4.8Cech_compactification_of_the_natural_numbers), denoted $\beta \mathbb N$.

Since it is a compactification of $\mathbb N$, it follows that $\mathbb N$ itself is a (countable) dense subset.

One property of this space is that all convergent sequences are *eventually constant*, meaning that if $( x_n )_n$ is a sequence in $\beta \mathbb N$ which converges to $x \in \beta \mathbb N$, then there is an $N$ such that $x_n = x$ for all $n \geq N$. In particular, no point in the remainder $\beta \mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N$ is the limit of a sequence in $\mathbb N$.

More details about these facts can be found on Dan Ma's Topology Blog: [Stone-Cech Compactification of the Integers – Basic Facts](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/stone-cech-compactification-of-the-integers-basic-facts/)